# Narrative questions related to TV shows / films

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Am I allowed to ask a question about narrative in the main site? Like if X character was a Deus Ex Machina or simillar. I'm asking this because it may be a question for a writing techniques or simillar page (I don't remember the name now).

The question is: "Was Arya a Deus Ex Machina act in the third episode from the last season of GoT?"

Comment: From your description, I'd be doubtful. Writers.SE might be a better fit but it will depend on the question.

Comment: It's still a little unclear to me specifically what kind of question you're describing, so I wouldn't downright deny it. But if it leans too much into the creative direction as opposed to the analytical direction, it might indeed be off-topic. Maybe you can flesh out the meta question a little more, though?

Comment: @Paulie_D It would be off-topic on Writing SE, since the question's about an existing work.

Comment: By "narrative/writing techniques", I guess you meant like some tropes?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I added the main question now.

Comment: @Paulie_D now updated.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is: "Was Arya a Deus Ex Machina act in the third episode from the last season of GoT?"

In it's current form, the question is on-topic but there's a *slight* possibility of it being considered by some members of the community as requiring "Opinion Based" answers which would drive it off-topic.

The issue is (it seems to me) **"what is the user's interpretation of a "Deus Ex Machina".**

Here's one definition:

> a plot device where an unexpected power or event resolves a seemingly hopeless situation, especially as a contrived plot device in a play or novel.[
>
> <sup>Wikipedia</sup>

Frankly, I'd err on the side posting the question and seeing what happens. I wouldn't vote to close it.

Comment: It's in the gray area this question. I'll post it see what happens.